# Adding a value at the end of a column in a multindex column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have a simple problem that probably has a simple solution but I couldn't found it anywhere. I have the following multindex column Dataframe:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(['A','B','C'], ['Datetime', 'Str', 'Ret']])
dfr = pd.DataFrame(columns=mux)

  |      A         |        B       |        C       |
  |Datetime|Str|Ret|Datetime|Str|Ret|Datetime|Str|Ret|
```

I need to add values one by one at the end of a specific subcolumn. For example add one value at the end of column A sub-column Datetime and leave the rest of the row as it is, then add another value to column B sub-column Str and again leave the rest of the values in the same row untouched and so on. So my questions are: Is it possible to target individual locations in this type of Dataframes? How? and also Is it possible to append not a full row but an individual value always at the end after the previous value without knowing where the end is?. Thank you so much for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `.loc`:

```
idx = len(dfr)  # get the index of the next row after the last one
dfr.loc[idx, ('A', 'Datetime')] = pd.to_datetime('2021-09-24')
dfr.loc[idx, ('B', 'Str')] = 'Hello'
dfr.loc[idx, ('C', 'Ret')] = 4.3
```

Output:

```
>>> dfr
                     A                  B                    C          
              Datetime  Str  Ret Datetime    Str  Ret Datetime  Str  Ret
0  2021-09-24 00:00:00  NaN  NaN      NaN  Hello  NaN      NaN  NaN  4.3
```

**Update**

> I mean for example when I have different number of values in different columns (for example 6 values in column A-Str but only 4 in column B-Datetime) but I don´t really know. In that case what I need is to add the next value in that column after the last one so I need to know the index of the last non Nan value of that particular column so I can use it in your answer because if I use len(dfr) while trying to add value to the column that only has 4 values it will end up in the 7th row instead of the 5th row, this is because one of the columns may have more values than the others.

You can do it easily using [`last_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.last_valid_index.html). Create a convenient function `append_to_col` to append values inplace in your dataframe:

```
def append_to_col(col, val):
    idx = dfr[col].last_valid_index()
    dfr.loc[idx+1 if idx is not None else 0, col] = val


# Fill your dataframe
append_to_col(('A', 'Datetime'), '2021-09-24')
append_to_col(('A', 'Datetime'), '2021-09-25')
append_to_col(('B', 'Str'), 'Hello')
append_to_col(('C', 'Ret'), 4.3)
append_to_col(('C', 'Ret'), 8.2)
append_to_col(('A', 'Datetime'), '2021-09-26')
```

Output:

```
>>> dfr
            A                  B                    C          
     Datetime  Str  Ret Datetime    Str  Ret Datetime  Str  Ret
0  2021-09-24  NaN  NaN      NaN  Hello  NaN      NaN  NaN  4.3
1  2021-09-25  NaN  NaN      NaN    NaN  NaN      NaN  NaN  8.2
2  2021-09-26  NaN  NaN      NaN    NaN  NaN      NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is helpful however I´m looking also to have the values added to the first available position of that particular column, for instance after adding the DateTime value, How can you add 'hello' to the first row instead of the second row while keeping the DateTime value? Maybe a solution is to remove all the Nan and move the values up to the first available position but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: thank you, this is the answer I was looking for. Now every time I need to add a new value I can simply define idx by looking at the row idx of the last non Nan of the column I want to add the value to, I'll google this.

Comment: I mean for example when I have different number of values in different columns (for example 6 values in column A-Str but only 4 in column B-Datetime) but I don´t really know. In that case what I need is to add the next value in that column after the last one so I need to know the index of the last non Nan value of that particular column so I can use it in your answer because if I use len(dfr) while trying to add value to the column that only has 4 values it will end up in the 7th row instead of the 5th row, this is because one of the columns may have more values than the others.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think it's what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. I also found another way whit the .count() method:      
{   idx=dfr[('B', 'Str')].count()  
dfr.loc[idx, ('B', 'Str')] = 'Hello'  }     
or in one line:         
{ dfr.loc[dfr[('B', 'Str')].count(), ('B', 'Str')] = 'Hello' }